# Shortcut to open dialog to insert icon

Tags: utf-8, character-map

When I google this I can't find it. But sometimes when I'm in the console and I'm fiddling around a certain key combination triggers a dialog to appear. In the dialog you can choose an icon to insert. Just like the icons you can use in for example whatsapp.

I tried al lot of combinations but I can't seem to find the right pair. The three times it happend it happend on accident.

What is the key combination to open this icon dialog?

Comment: Are you talking about the Character Viewer invoked with fn-E?

Comment: Yes!!! Thats it

Comment: @agarza could you post this as an answer so I can give you credit. I know it's a simple question but still... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the **Character Viewer** and can be opened with the key combination <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: Apple's screenshot of the Character Viewer]
<sup>Source: Apple</sup>

Additional information is available on Apple's support page "[Use emoji and symbols on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/mac)"